# Multiplying numbers and outputting result in a file in SCHEME

Tags: file, scheme, racket, readfile

I am new to the concept of SCHEME and just started learning Scheme (and DrRacket). Started with some online resources including, [DrRacket Docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html). Following this and some other references online, I am trying to solve a basic problem which involves reading 2 numbers from a file (data.inp), multiplying the numbers and displaying the output in a different file (result.out).

So far, I have been able to come up with following code,

```
#lang racket

(define (file->char_list path)

(call-with-input-file path

(lambda (input-port)

 (let loop ((x (read-char input-port)))

   (cond 

    ((eof-object? x) '())

    (#t (begin (cons x (loop (read-char input-port))))))))))

(define (yb) 

     ;(call-with-input-file "data.inp"
     ;(lambda (in) (read-string 14 in)
 ; ))

  ;(call-with-output-file "result.out"
  ;(lambda (output-port)
            ; (display "(* x x)" output-port))) 
; Fill in the blank
 ;(fprintf (current-output-port) "Done!~n"))

  (string->number (apply string (file->char_list "data.inp"))))
 (yb)
```

I am stuck at reading numbers from a file (data.inp) and multiplying them. I have references some previous stackoverflow questions but I am sort of stuck at this point. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scheme, most of the time you'll probably want to use the default "current" ports for input and output. On most Unix systems, the default current input port is linked to `stdin` and the default current output port is linked to `stdout`.

With that in mind, reading in two numbers and writing out their product is basically:

```
(display (* (read) (read)))
```

Now, if you want to use actual input and output files, like you mentioned in your question, then you can either wrap with `with-input-from-file`/`with-output-to-file` (which temporarily changes the current input and output port):

```
(with-input-from-file "data.inp"
  (lambda ()
    (with-output-to-file "result.out"
      (lambda ()
        (display (* (read) (read)))))))
```

or you can explicitly specify ports, and leave the current/default input and output ports unchanged:

```
(call-with-input-file "data.inp"
  (lambda (in)
    (call-with-output-file "result.out"
      (lambda (out)
        (display (* (read in) (read in)) out)))))
```

Comment: This worked and better than what I had planned to do. To take it a step further I am now trying to print the 2 numbers which were multiplied and show it in same file as the output. Tried using `(display ((read in) (read in)) (* (read in) (read in)) out)` and `(display (((read in) (read in)) * (read in) (read in)) out)` but I get error pointing out number of arguments.